# Jquery issue using '+=' for animation in IE

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Can anyone help me workout why this isn't working in IE?
I have a product shot that when rolled over animates down relieving more info below it.
This works on all other browsers just not IE < 7 any idea or other solutions?

Currently the hover effect work as it should but the "roll off" does nothing in IE
thanks

```
$('#topProducts li').hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('.topProdImg').stop().animate({
        bottom: '-=140'
    }, 500)
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.topProdImg').stop().animate({
        bottom: '+=0'
    }, 500)
});
```

css:

```
.topProducts ul li img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:1px #ebebeb solid;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Bottom Margins instead.

```
$('#topProducts li').hover(
function () {
   $(this).find('.topProdImg').stop(true,true).animate({marginBottom:'-140px'},200);
}, function () {

    $(this).find('.topProdImg').stop(true,true).animate({marginBottom:'0px'},400);
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try using `px`

```
$('#topProducts li').hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('.topProdImg').stop().animate({
        bottom: '-=140px'
    }, 500)
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.topProdImg').stop().animate({
        bottom: '0px' //it doesn't sense to apply +=0
    }, 500)
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, sorry I thought this was working. But now on all over browsers on rollout the image slides up to +140px??